# Attach database to sqlite while also specifying schema

Tags: python, sqlite

I am integration testing my company's application and I have been tasked with using sqlite specifically to mock our SQL Server. In the integration testing, I am calling some mssql queries. These queries go something like this:

```
SELECT
    column1
    ,column2
FROM
    [databaseName].dbo.TableName t1
```

I am able to attach `dbo` in sqlite, like so:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES)
cur = con.cursor()
attach = "ATTACH DATABASE ? AS dbo"
cur.execute(attach, (":memory:",))

table = """CREATE TABLE dbo.TableName(
Column1 INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
,Column2 INT
);"""
cur.execute(table)

query = """INSERT INTO dbo.TableName (Column1, Column2) VALUES (?, ?);"""
cur.execute(query, (1, 999))
```

I have been unsuccessful in creating a solution where `DatabaseName` can be called- something like,

```
CREATE TABLE databaseName.dbo.TableName(....);
```

I have already tried this code, which fails:

```
attach = "ATTACH DATABASE ? AS databaseName.dbo"
cur.execute(attach, (":memory:",))
```

How can I implement this kind of solution in Python?

Comment: If you use SQL Server in production, use it in tests too, not a completely different database with a different dialect of SQL.

Comment: Hey man, these are my project requirements, which weren’t set by me. So I can’t change this. If I could use sql server I would, but I can’t.

Comment: Well, you can't do that in SQLite.

Comment: Again, what you're trying **doesn't work** in SQLite. It is a different product than SQL Server with different syntax and feature set. It is not possible to use it as a drop in replacement for queries like your example. The differences get even bigger with more complicated queries. Your project is doomed to failure from the beginning because of this. You've been given an impossible task. Tell whoever came up with this idea that. It'll save you a lot of pain and futile effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite won't allow you a `db.schema.table` reference, that's just the way it works.

You can [`ATTACH DATABASE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) with a `schema-name` containing a space, dot or another character by enclosing it in single quotes, but then you also need to access it in the same way, which will not work with your SQL Server queries.

```sql
ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS 'db.schema';
CREATE TABLE 'db.schema'.table (id INT);

.databases
-- main:
-- test.schema:

.tables
-- test.schema.t

SELECT * FROM test.schema.t
-- Error: near ".": syntax error

SELECT * FROM 'test.schema'.t
-- nothing but no error
```

All in all, it's just not doable to test a large number of SQL Server queries on SQLite, because of bracketed names `[]`, incompatible functions like `IIF()`, or things like `VALUES` expressions.